# Using custom rules in amazon security groups issues

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

So my question is pretty straight forward:

I have two ec2-classic instances,
say A(with security group sg-A) and B(with security group sg-B)

the rules in sg-A is :

```
Type | Protocol | Port Range | Source
RDP  | TCP      | 3389       | 0.0.0.0/0
```

the rules in sg-B is :

```
Type    | Protocol  | Port Range | Source
All TCP | TCP       | 0 - 65535  | sg-A
All UDP | UDP       | 0 - 65535  | sg-A
All ICMP| All       | N/A        | sg-A
RDP     | TCP       | 3389       | 0.0.0.0/0
```

With these rules i do not even get a reply in ping from A to B

But when i change All ICMP rule in sg-B from sg-A to 0.0.0.0/0 , i receive a reply.

Can you tell me what is wrong when it is sg-A ?

---

Edit:

B hosts a webserver and A wants to access the same.
I found that I have to change All TCP in sg-B 
from sg-A to 0.0.0.0/0 (or direct IP of A) 
to make the webserver accessible.

I can't find anything logically incorrect, is it possible that Amazon is malfunctioning ?

Comment: Are the machines in the same AWS region and on the same AWS account?

Comment: yes they are in the same region and account

Answer (score -1):

Has it been resolved?

If you ssh onto A, ping B's private ip, it should work well. But not for public ip.

REFER FROM: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups

Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the instances that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).